# resx resources or database for globalization resources

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, globalization, resx

I have been trying to get culture specific resources to work on an asp.net mvc 3 application.

If I have a LanguageResources.resx and a LanguageResources.en-UK.resx in my App_GlobalResources folder then I get an error "The namespace 'Resources' already contains a definition for 'LanguageResources'"

This is the end of a long line of issues that I have had with trying to get culture specific resources to work.  I must say, I'm not impressed with the documentation Microsoft provide for using this feature.

I'm considering using a database table to store my culture specific strings instead, then I can just build a dictionary of all the values that will be available to my controller and views.

Has anyone else made such a decision, or have any direct knowledge on performance issues related to using a database for culture specific strings?

Has anyone else given up on resources too?

Comment: Probably not related but you should be using en-GB. There is no en-UK code for cultures.

Comment: I can work with resources without any problems. I'm interested, which other kind of problems do you have?

Comment: I have changed the files to correct culture codes (my mistake!!) and now they don't come into effect when I change the culture of the specific thread.  I have had a lot of problems, one of them being having to use the publicResXFileCodeGenerator custom tool so that the strings are accessible.  It would be good if this worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit, I tried to reproduce your defect and I was successful. It looks like, Visual Studio generates additional class when you add something.en-UK.resx. Strange. It should not allow you to add anything like this in the first place for there is no such culture.

How to resolve the problem? Just add LanguageResources.en-GB.resx and **delete**
LanguageResources.en-GB.resx. That helps.

I would not use database for storing language-related resources, unless they are changing very frequently or must be entered by end users (i.e. there are some kind of templates).
Using the database hurts Localizability and requires much effort. It is hard to design correctly (I have seen a lot of mistakes in that area). Don't go that road unless you really have to.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that has stopped the error, but now the .cs file is always empty, even if I run the custom tool using the context menu option.  This is just causing the application to fall back to the default strings I think, because I'm trying to test some odd string using fo-FO, I have tried with the PublicResXFileCodeGenerator and the global default custom tool.  I think I'm getting closer, but I still think this is a very awkward process.

Comment: I have answered this as correct, as my problem was UK instead of GB.  For anyone else reading with problems, I was setting the Thread.CurrentCulture with no results.  I needed to set the Thread.CurrentUICulture for the appropriate resources to be used.